# Manjaro NVidia 1050 black areas while moving windows

Tags: linux, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, thinkpad, manjaro

I've ThinkPad X1 Extreme with NVidia 1050 TI MAX-Q.
I've installed Manjaro Linux with only discrete card mode in bios.

Driver: `VIDEO-NVIDIA 2018.08.09`
OS: `Linux n8 4.19.32-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 27 18:55:07 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

When I'm moving windows I'm seeing black areas like in screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

[link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xM_fvKjBxYA)

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: That's not a bug, it's a feature.  You turned on eraser mode.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 I was going to say that in my question: `how to disable eraser feature` :D

Comment: unfortunately fixed problem by switching to KDE Neon...

Comment: Seems like in OpenSource world nobody wants to take responsibility for quality. So that's why I sold this ThinkPad X1E and bought MacBook Pro 15', cause Mac and Mac OS done for people. I'll let Linux Desktop lovers fight with incompatibilities themselves. I'm out)